# Before any thread dies will it call notify for all objects waiting on thread reference

Tags: java, android

Please check bellow code it work fine even though i haven't called notify().
So my question is that does any thread will call notifyAll() implicitly before it dies ?

```
class ThreadB extends Thread{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
                total += i;
        }
    }
}
public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
        synchronized (b) {
            b.wait();
            System.out.println("ThreadA.main()");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you shouldn't `wait` on a thread. It usually indicates a misunderstanding of how threading works. If you want to wait until a thread ends, you need to use `join`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long,%20int)) states

> As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

Regarding your comment

> as your comment it will call `notifyAll()` when it terminates but what
>   happens if thread is terminated and after that we called `join()` method

[Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.join%28long%29) a recent implementation of `java.lang.Thread`. It also checks [`Thread#isAlive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive--). When a thread has finished, `isAlive` will return `false`.

The scenario is as follows: the thread terminates, its internal `isAlive` flag is turned to `false`, and `notifyAll` is called on it. The other thread calls `join` on it and checks `isAlive`. Since it returns `false`, the call to `join` returns immediately.

Comment: What happens if ThreadB completes before ThreadA is able to call wait?

Comment: @smith Calls to `notify` or `notifyAll` are not "remembered". The thread that called `wait` will block indefinitely (in this example).

Comment: Figured that would happen, wanted to verify first.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis as your comment it will call notifyAll() when it terminates but what happens if thread is terminated and after that we called join() method